# How to sync Sqlite on Android with remote Sqlite

Tags: java, android, python, django, sqlite

I have simple page created with Django with simple database in Sqlite. I create app on Android with Android Studio with Sqlite db and I want in the easiest way sync this databases. It can be done for example by the button "sync".

Thank's for help

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You are suppost to show some sort of own effort, e.g. sample code. Stackoverflow is not about other writing code for you, but we are happy to help at points where you are stuck.

Comment: And please clarify the type of sync: one way, two ways, with or w/o conflict resolution...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This is not a free code-writing service nor tutorial site. You're expected to have already done basic research, to present the code you've tried with a description of how it's not working and what the expected result would be. As it stands, your question is "too broad"